# Problems with USB to WiFi adapter TP-LINK TL-WN722N v2 and Hotspot creation

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I use Linux Mint 20.1 and am trying to properly install USB WiFi device TP-LINK TL-WN722N v2

I first installed driver R8188eu following instructions from

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Also this driver was recommended on following link

http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N_v2

Then I followed first Answer from the topic

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341804/tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-driver-problem-ubuntu-20-04/1348355#1348355

and tried to instead install driver 8812au

Now when I type

```
sudo dkms status
```

I get

```
rtl8812au, 5.9.3.2, 5.4.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
```

as it should be the case

but when I type

```
inxi -Fxxxz
```

I get regarding the mentioned device

```
Device-3: TP-Link TL-WN722N v2 type: USB driver: r8188eu bus ID: 1-8:8 chip ID: 2357:010c serial: IF: wlxd037454c08ee state: down mac: IF-ID-1: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A
```

So it's not the same USB driver as I get with dkms status

I have no idea how to change this, as I have uninstalled the first driver, than installed the new one but to no avail.

Operationally wise I can connect to existing wifi network, but I cannot use my wifi adapter to create a hotspot.

Any idea what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this works for linux mint 20.1 regarding USB-WiFi adapter from the topic

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install rtl8188eu-dkms
```

After rebooting your mint the adapter is fully functional and can also serve as a hotspot